# Magento failed require_once php file

Tags: php, magento, fopen

I am trying to require_once a php file in Magento, so that i can use the functions inside the file. No matter where i place the php file, or where i try to require it, the same error occurs:

**`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://127.0.0.1/ezzence/functions.php' (include_path='C:\wamp\www\ezzence\app\code\local;C:\wamp\www\ezzence\app\code\community;C:\wamp\www\ezzence\app\code\core;C:\wamp\www\ezzence\lib;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\ezzence\app\design\frontend\default\theme317\template\page\html\head.phtml on line 28`**

The PHP file only contains a single function, so the php file itself is not the problem. It's like PHP cant find my php file. I try to require it like this:

```
<?php require_once($this->getBaseUrl() . 'functions.php');?>
```

Originally i wanted the file to be in **`skin/theme/default/inc/`**, but for testing purpose i moved it to root.

I have checked that i have allow_url_fopen = On in my php.ini, but i dont know if that affects require_once method.

Any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot include a php file over http. This is wrong:

```
required once 'http://example.com/some_file.php'
```

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
require_once($this->getBaseDir() . 'functions.php'
```

But this also is not the Magento way of doing it. You should create a module and place the function inside a helper. Then you can call the function without needing the `require_once` statement like this: `Mage::helper('helper_alias_here')->doSomething()`

**Edit** *and a bit off topic*
If you use Magento the proper way you don't need to use `require` statements unless you are rewriting a controller class.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer. I always look to do it the proper way :) I will look into it

Comment: How about, when you want to include Mage.php ? Do you not want to use require_once there?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann If you need to include mage.php then you need require_once. But you only need to do this if you create custom php files. But you should use the internal MVC and create a controller and an action for your custom needs.

Comment: I dont know if i understand what you mean exactly. I only need a helper class with some functions in it. Would it be incorrect to require_once('app/mage.php') ?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann. You don't need to require anything. Just create a module with a helper. In your helper you can place as many functions as you want and you will be able to use them anywhere without requiring anything.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this solution is much better, and easy to implement :)

Comment: using include_once or require_once give Coding standard error. is there another way in magento to include files?

Answer (score 1):

getBaseUrl function is for getting the URL not PATH

```
Mage::getBaseDir()
```

this function returns right magento installation path

Comment: Lets say that i want the php file in skin/mytheme/default/inc/ , what is then the optimal solution of linking ?

Comment: Mage::getBaseDir('skin')."mytheme/default/inc/functions.php";

Bu i think that helper is better and proper solution for that

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * Construct initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->configvariables = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->configvariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->configvariables, null, true);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Your Code";
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Note: Here we need to add absolute path of files which we want to include_once or require_once. MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command and this module placed into the vendor directory.**